# Vector GIS.se logo for use in posters/presentations?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

SVG versions of some SE site logos are [available](https://stackapps.com/questions/347/svg-versions-of-the-logos). Could the compass logo for GIS.se be made available as SVG as well?

Comment: I've passed this along to our designer; hopefully he'll get back to you soon. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I emailed you the logo in vector format. In the future I'll make the vector logo available on this site for everyone to download.

Edit: added [Dropbox link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2296037/gis-logo.eps) to the logo vector file.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Jin!

Comment: Is the vector format available for download yet?

Comment: @blah238 I edited my answer with the .eps file link.

Comment: What license does the logo use? :)